# Pass an authenticated user from application to B2C and back to application to update token

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We have a .net5 razor application which is connected to our B2C environment. In the application we have a process which updates some of the user's details including their name. We are currently displaying their name in the nav bar of the application and are getting this from `User.Identity.Name`.

So, when the user's name gets updated, then the value held in `User.Identity.Name` is not updated, so the name remains as it was.

Ideally we would like to pass the user to a screen in B2C to update the token which will get their updated name and then return to the application all in one go without the user having to do anything. Alternatively, we need to make a call to update the token behind the scene and then when the page reloads, then the name will be updated due to the token having been updated.

Currently we can't see a way of doing this, as the available `asp-actions` under the `asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity"` are limited to: Challenge, EditProfile, ResetPassord, SignIn and SIgnOut.

If we pass the user through the ResetPAssword user flow and then back to the application, then the token has updated and we get back the updated user's name. However, we wouldn't want to have to get through this process if they only update their name.

How can we go about doing this?

Comment: If you pass them through sign in again, they should get sent to /authorize with SSO and be issued a new token. This is why we recommend using our profile edit policy, you could even embed it into your app with an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

As [Jas Suri - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8357357/jas-suri-msft) commented [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66874009/pass-an-authenticated-user-from-application-to-b2c-and-back-to-application-to-up/66965623#comment118301603_66874009), the way to do this is to pass the user to the SignUpSignIn policy, as because they are already authenticated, they will be passed through the policy screen and back to the application without any user interaction.